# Construct a triangle, given its angle at the vertex, and the altitude and the median drawn to the base.

Tags: geometric-construction

[image]
The problem is from a book. Also it gives a hint: "Double the median extending it past the base, connect the endpoint the with the vertices at the base, and consider the parallelogram thus formed.".

The image below is my interpretation of the problem. In the left is some random triangle with the colored segments and angle as the given. In the right is some attempt at reconstructing it with the given (starting with the point A). I can't seem to reconcile the hint with my attempt: I can't construct the parellelogram that it is talking about. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem? Any hint?

Answer (score 4):

The black angle at the start is the angle that is given. The line is the base and the two red dots are the vertex and the median.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. After studying why your solution works, I finally figure out how the hint can be used.

Comment: Yeah, the trick is to build a paralelogram with appropriate angles and two vertices on the line and use the fact that the diagonals bisect themselves

Comment: I used a different approach that the book uses a lot. Base on secant(chord) and tangent of a point on a circle (dunno exactly the name of the theorem).

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/OTMsJ

Comment: its basically the same, you just transpassed the angle smarter